# does manually resigning a changed zone file with the same keys break the DNSSEC support from the upstream parent zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec

I send the ds set of example.company.com to my company.com provider. I also manage a couple of subdomains which are subject to change eventually: subdomain1.example.company.com and subdomain2.example.company.com. I add the DS set of these subdomains inside example.company.com zone file and eventually some records in the subdomains will change and I will have to resign the whole file. I want to use the same keys so as to not have to mess with the static example.company.com but just update the signatures on the 2 subdomains. However, I noticed after a test that the RRSIG for records that were not changed, did change in the new resigning. Isnt the signing process deterministic? Does my old DS set still hold up? Does this mean that for every update of my signed subdomains I have to change my example.company.com Ds set or something?

Comment: Are you saying the signature changed or the RRSIG changed? The same signing key will result in the same signature for the same data but the RRSIG will change as it includes additional information such as inception and expiration which is based upon the signing time.

Comment: no the rrsig changed. But I guess you explained here why. I did not consider the expiration time being relevant in relation to signature generation